# Can't configure node.js on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, node.js, cygwin

I have problem with configuring NODE.JS. I was trying to install node.js with [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) tutorial, but when i typed:

> ./configure

I got error:
[image: screen]

I will be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unable to remap error you've encounted is often an indication that you need to run the `rebaseall` program. Rerun the setup file you used to install the your cygwin environment, then run `rebaseall -v` and that should fix it. You'll need to make sure that no cygwin programs are running when you run `rebaseall`.

Comment: i'll try it and than write result

Comment: hmmm i need to raun it in cmd, right? If yes, i get error. Somthing like rebaseall is not executable programm or command. What i can do to solve it?

Comment: Yes, you need to run in the command prompt. Did you run the cygwin installer and make sure it was installed? If so look inside you cygwin directory for the rebaseall.exe file and run the command from there.

Comment: I added C:\cygwin\bin to PATH with:
`SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin` and when i typed rebaseall -v i got same error. 

In C:\cygwin\bin is rebase.exe and rebaseall (without ext)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion about running rebaseall. Step 1 is to close all Cygwin applications. Step 2 is to use Windows explorer to open C:\cygwin\bin\ and double click on ash.exe. This opens a shell prompt that can be used to run rebaseall.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use the mingw version. I already built v0.4.2 and left it here: [node-v0.4.2-win32.7z](http://www.graphnode.com/stuff/node-v0.4.2-win32.7z). It works on windows 7.